# JDBC MSSQL class loading compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have been trying to run the code below on IntelliJ but it doesn't seem to work even though I have tried adding MSSQL JDBC driver to either module dependencies or global libraries.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    testConnection();
}

public static boolean testConnection() {
    final String DEFAULT_DRIVER_CLASS = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    try {
    Class.forName(DEFAULT_DRIVER_CLASS);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=testApp");
    String query = "Select * from Employee";
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    if (rs!=null){
        System.out.println(rs);
        return true;
        }
        System.out.println(rs);
        return false;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

It seems to have the SQLException all the time, here is the stack trace:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:1e971545-e8a0-4361-b033-29758a00df94
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5036)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3668)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3627)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2935)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2456)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
at Main.testConnection(Main.java:16)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I copied the url from the Datasource and used it for getConnection().

Comment: Post your code and stacktrace directly into the question. No images or screenshots.

Comment: Did you try resolving the other compilation error? You can temporarily surround db connection logic with try-catch.

Comment: I just edited my post above, hope that help. There is only one compilation error which is the jdbc one.

Comment: This is a *compilation error*. It has nothing to do with JDBC or MSSQL 'not working' whatsoever. NB The `Class.forName()` line has been unnecessary since 2007.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify my problem, sorry for the confusion everyone

Comment: Your edit constitutes a new question. You should delete this one and ask the new one as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your method signature for `testConnection` method. Write it as below;

```
public boolean testConnection() throws Exception {
   ...
}
```

and in your `main` method also do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the problem is that Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); is supposed to be able to find the "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class because I have added the jbdc driver (jar file) as library or module dependency. Your solution is just a workaround so the code can compile but I want to connect to the database though.

Comment: @TienNguyen No. This is not a 'workaround', it is a required code change. At the moment the only problem you have is that your code doesn't compile, and this will fix it. You don't know whether you can connect or not yet, and you can't know until you fix this. Try it before arguing. It would be better to declare all the actual exceptions that can be thrown, which include `ClassNotFoundException`, rather than just declaring `throws Exception`.

Comment: I am sorry, I have just tried to catch the Exception as you said. I am totally a noobie and I did misunderstand you before. I have edited my question and would be very grateful if you can have a look and help me with the problem.